# Deserialze different set of data into different classes based on Class name from table

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a table like this

```
ReportID   ReportName     ClassName
-----------------------------------
124       Project Details     kipProjectModel
325       Program Master      kipProgrammeMaster
543       Resource Master     kipResourceMaster
.....
...
..
.----------------------------------
```

Also I have an API from which it return different JSON reports based on the ID we pass to it

```
http://myapi.com/reportid=39
```

So I am getting a JSON report doesnt matter what ever the ID is. But it should desterilize as an object of that class from that table above. Since its a string name I have no idea how to achieve that.

I am using newtonsoft json

Environment is .NET Core 5.0

Answer (score 1):

This method can build a generic list type from class name. Note that class name must be full name, including namespace:

```
private static Type GetListTypeByElementName(string elementClassName)
{
    var genericType = typeof(List<>);
    var elementTypes = new Type[] { Type.GetType(elementClassName) };
    return genericType.MakeGenericType(elementTypes);
}
```

If your api response is a "plain" object, not a collection, you can get the type by simply doing:

```
var reportType = Type.GetType(reportTypeName);
```

Then you can use it to deserialize with the appropiate overload of DeserializeObject. Example:

```
var classAList = new List<ClassA> {
    new ClassA { ClassAId = 1, ClassAName = "Item A-1" },
    new ClassA { ClassAId = 2, ClassAName = "Item A-2" },
    new ClassA { ClassAId = 3, ClassAName = "Item A-3" },
    new ClassA { ClassAId = 4, ClassAName = "Item A-4" },
    new ClassA { ClassAId = 5, ClassAName = "Item A-5" }
};

var classBList = new List<ClassB> {
    new ClassB { ClassBId = 1, ClassBName = "Item B-1" },
    new ClassB { ClassBId = 2, ClassBName = "Item B-2" },
    new ClassB { ClassBId = 3, ClassBName = "Item B-3" },
    new ClassB { ClassBId = 4, ClassBName = "Item B-4" },
    new ClassB { ClassBId = 5, ClassBName = "Item B-5" }
};

var jsonClassAList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classAList);
var jsonClassBList = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classBList);

var classAClassName = "TestDeserialize.ClassA";
var classBClassName = "TestDeserialize.ClassB";

var deserializedClassAList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonClassAList, GetListTypeByElementName(classAClassName));
var deserializedClassBList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonClassBList, GetListTypeByElementName(classBClassName));
```

Note than the deserialized collection will be a List of the correct type, but at compile time it will be a list of objects, without the specific type.

Classes definitions:

```
class ClassA
{
    public int ClassAId { get; set; }
    public string ClassAName { get; set; }
}
class ClassB
{
    public int ClassBId { get; set; }
    public string ClassBName { get; set; }
}
```